# Information about the application integrating with my SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, code-signing

I am developing an SDK for the application I am working on. But only authorised apps should be able to integrate with this SDK.

Most of the SDKs use a secret API key, which when revealed gives you access to the SDK's functionality.

I would like to detect if the application has registered with me on some console. So, when the application initialises my SDK, I would check some signing or something similar to detect if this is the very application that is registered with me on my console.

Is there any way to get this signing information or something similar to detect what application is integrating with my SDK?

Comment: The key is for working with the backend, your sdk should always provide full function, if the key is wrong, they cant get any info or you can use some checking with your backend to return value from your function or not

Comment: The concern around this is that a hacker on a jailbroken device can access my app's runtime and get to know about that secret key. Post that, I will be screwed.
Android has packageManager API which gives info about the package. I was looking for a similar API.

Comment: I think this is the concern that the your client who integrate the sdk will need to face, not ur sdk, any other sdk is doing the same thing i suppose, all let the dev to control where to secure the key

Comment: Agreed. But that means the onus is on the developer. I think a more specific question would be asking for an alternative of PackageManager type API on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried certificate pinning?